# Forcing runOnUiThread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, synchronization, background-process

I am trying to force a background thread to publish progress, like an AsyncTask, but I am failing miserably. I don't understand why it does not work.

I begin the background thread like this:

```
new Thread(() -> {
    doInBackground();
}).start();
```

Inside `doInBackground()`, I have a loop like this:

```
...
synchronized (this) {
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        ...
        if (i % 100 == 0) {
           System.out.println("### INNER ### ");
           activity.runOnUiThread(this::onProgressUpdate);
        }
    }
 }
```

And `onProgressUpdate()` is simply

```
onProgressUpdate() {
     System.out.println("-------------");
}
```

What I expect is that, for each `### INNER ###`  I see an intercalated `-------------`. Yet, I see all the `### INNER ###`  first, and then all the `-------------`. So the line

```
activity.runOnUiThread(this::onProgressUpdate);
```

is not being executed at the moment I want. I tried adding and removing several `synchronized (this)` everywhere, without success.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: IMO this is a correct behavior and the output depends on the threads execution.
Both the prints are printing in different threads. That's why you don't see a sequential execution.
By the time you post something to UI thread, your current thread is free and executes the next print ("### INNER ###) statement.

Comment: I see. So, how to solve the problem?

Comment: You are already updating the progress on the UI thread. What's the exact issue?
You will never be sure when the main thread will execute your runnable.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I was clear enough. The exact issue is the one in the title of the thread: to force the runOnUiThread to get `### INNER ###`, then `-------------`, then `### INNER ###`, then `-------------`, and so on. Your answer seems to be that this is impossible unless I do everything in the same thread (hence blocking it while doing the `doInBackground` tasks). But then, how the `publishProgress` method in AsyncTask performs this?

Comment: AsyncTask internally does something very similar to your code. It posts the job on the main Handler which delivers the job to main UI thread. The async operation is never disturbed during this. You can try something like this
```
 val semaphore = Semaphore(1)
        val mainHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
for (your logic) {
          try {
               semaphore.acquire()
               mainHandler.post { 
                  /* do your main ui work*/ 
                   semaphore.release()
               }
           } catch (e: Exception) {}
         
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can try something like below for your use case.

```
  val semaphore = Semaphore(1)
        val mainHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
        for (your logic) {
            try {
                semaphore.acquire()
                mainHandler.post {
                    /* do your main ui work*/
                    semaphore.release()
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {

            } 
        }
```

Comment: This worked. The semaphore stops the execution of the background thread. Thanks for pointing me to `Semaphore`, I didn't know about it.